# Ajax срабатывает сразу несколько раз

Tags: jquery, ajax

Почему ajax запрос срабатывает сразу несколько раз?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    let height_win = false;
    if ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - 200 && !height_win) {
        height_win = true;
        indexcat = $('.news_category.active').index() + 1;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/modal?route=news/id=' + indexcat,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function success(response) {
                if (response.data != "") {
                    if (response.data.length > 0) {
                        var el = $(response.data);
                        $("#news").append(el).masonry('appended', el, true);
                    }
                    height_win = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Но если в условии сделать просто:

```
if ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() && !height_win) /* скролить полностью до конца страницы
```

То все работает хорошо.

Comment: Кто дал переменной имя индекскиска ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что `$(window).scroll` плюс `if` с условием `>=` плюс флаг `height_win` явно не так использован

```js
let i = 0,
  wh = $(window).height(),
  dh = $(document).height(),
  height_win = false;
$(window).scroll(function () {
  let
    whSt = $(window).scrollTop(),
    v1 = wh + whSt,
    v2 = dh - 200;
    if (v1 > v2 && !height_win) {
      i++;
      console.log(v1 + ' > or = ' + v2);
      console.log('scroll event firing ' + i + ' times');
      height_win = true;
    }
    if (v1 < v2) {
      height_win = false;
    }
})
```

```css
#scroll{height:1000px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroll"><div>
```